# Comparing route to current request in Symfony

Tags: routes, symfony1, navigation

For my site navigation I'd like to indicate the current page. If each page in the navigation has its own route is there a way to see if the current request matches the route? Something like:

`$request->getRoute() == '@my_route'`

Or, more generally, is there an idiomatic way of setting the active page when creating site navigation in Symfony?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Or, more generally, is there an idiomatic way of setting the active page when creating site navigation in Symfony?*

Don't use sfContext::getInstance(), route names or internal uris for this. There are several ways to achieve navigation menu highlighting with Symfony, personnaly I like setting a request attribute (eg. in a controller), like this:

```
<?php
// ...
  public function executeFoo(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $request->setAttribute('section', 'blah');
  }
```

Then in your template:

```
<ul>
  <li class="<?php echo 'blah' === $sf_request->getAttribute('section') ? 'active' : '' ?>">
    <a href="<php echo url_for('@my_route') ?>">Blah</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can even add the `section` parameter from your routes in the `routing.yml` file:

```
my_route:
  url: /foo
  param: { module: foo, action: bar, section: blah }
```

Then in your template if you do so, be careful to check for a request parameter nstead of an attribute:

```
<ul>
  <li class="<?php echo 'blah' === $sf_request->getParameter('section') ? 'active' : '' ?>">
    <a href="<php echo url_for('@my_route') ?>">Blah</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Simple yet efficient, right? But f you need more complex navigatioin (especially nested menus), you should be thinking using some more full-featured plugins or symfony-based CMSes like Sympal, Diem or ApostropheCMS.

Answer (score 1):

You could try work with the following:

```
In template:
$route = $sf_context->getInstance()->getRouting()->getCurrentRouteName();

In action:
$route = sfContext::getInstance()->getRouting()->getCurrentRouteName();
```

What it returns is the route name as you've defined in routing. So for example if you've got a routing rule called "@search_results", the above method would return "search_results".

Maybe there's a better way, but I'm also using this to set the current active page in my layouts... by adding a "selected" class to a navigation element if the current route name matches "xxx".

Answer (score 0):

I've created a helper, added it to the standard_helpers and I create navigations links using this instead of link_to:

```
function thu_menu($name, $uri, $options = array())
{
  return link_to_unless(strpos(sfContext::getInstance()->getRouting()->getCurrentInternalUri(true), $uri) !== false, $name, $uri, $options);
}
```

I don't like sfContext::getInstance(), but this was the only way that I found.