# How to generate a multiple level navigation menu based on a doctrine Nested Set in Symfony?

Tags: javascript, symfony1, doctrine, navigation, nested

My model is implemented using Doctrine's Nested Set behaviour. It's a simple hierarchical model where Categories have Sub-categories that in turn have Items.

Is there a plugin, or a pattern I can implement that will generate the navigation for me, starting from the schema.yml? I am thinking of a fully-fledged solution, with detection of current page / module, taking into account user privilege, probably supporting javascript and surely CSS.

A fellow SOer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739923/comparing-route-to-current-request-in-symfony/2754746#2754746) that a CMS layer such as Apostrophe is to be used. Overkill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ioMenuPlugin is the best menu plugin I could find. Period.

I'd try to "translate" your nested set structure into ioMenuPlugin' items or try to migrate it to ioDoctrineMenuPlugin.

Comment: I could not get the Nested Set behaviour to play out, so for now I will hardcode my menu entries in the routing.yml. This works like a charm, but it is still not optimal. Good to know the support is out there. Good tip!